# Sendkeys infinite loop

Tags: c#, events, sendkeys, raw-input, keystroke

I'm using RawInput methods to intercept global keyboard keystrokes then send a string to the focused foregroundwindow, my problem is when i use `sendkeys.send()` i'm getting an infinite loop (the event is triggered each time)

i've tried to delete the event then add it but didn't work, i found on some topics that the problem appears because the place where i sent the string still focused but i need it to still focused, e.g. of what i'm doing :

- user press numpad0 in facebook messenger
- i remplace the numpad0 with my own string

**UPDATED**

```
    public static bool Keypressed = false;
    private void OnKeyPressed(object sender, RawInputEventArg e)
    {
        if (Keypressed){Keypressed=false;return;}

        if (cpt == 0)
        {
            cpt++;
            Console.WriteLine(e.KeyPressEvent.Name);
            //Check the Device name first !!!!
            //if(e.KeyPressEvent.Name.Contains(Settings.Default.DeviceName) || Settings.Default.DeviceName.Contains(e.KeyPressEvent.Name)) { }
            String ActiveProcess = ActiveApp.getActiveProccess();

            switch (ActiveProcess)
            {
                case "chrome":
                    if(API.getChromeUrl().Contains("facebook") || API.getChromeUrl().Contains("messenger"))
                    {

                        SendKeys.Send("1");
                        //Clipboard.SetText(""+Previous);
                        Console.WriteLine(API.getChromeUrl());
                        Keypressed = true;

                        // String Previous = Clipboard.GetText();
                        // Clipboard.SetText(FBEmo.numpad0);



                    }
                    break;
                case "mozzila":
                    break;
                case "Skype":
                    break;
                case "Viber":
                    break;


            }
            Console.WriteLine(ActiveProcess);
```

Comment: If I'm following, you are hooking keypress events, and when there's a keypress, you are simulating a keyptess, your hook is catching it, and so on. Have you considered having a flag (say "bool myKeypress") that you set right before you sendKeys (and clearing right afterwards). If your hook gets called while that flag is set, you just ignore it.

Comment: @Flydog57 yes, even with a flag the event will always be active, so when i turn the flag true it resumes

Comment: I don't see anything that's flag-like in your code

Comment: @Flydog57 see the update

Comment: its like if the event is always in some queue and every time starts, when i reopen the app window it stops when i focus on the messenger field it comes back

Comment: Nope. Set keyPressed to true right **before** you send the key. I don't remember if SendKeys is synchronous (SendMessage) or async (PostMessage). If it's synchronous, clear the flag right after the SendKeys call

Comment: @Flydog57 nothing changed, i dnt think a flag would solve the problem since its a loop : 
1st iteration : do the code
2nd iteration : keypressed true so do it false and return 
3rd iteration : do the code again.
i need to break entirely from the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works fine by using [InputSimulator](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/520/simulating-keypress-in-the-right-way-using-inputsimulator-with-csharp-in-winforms) instead of Sendkeys.Send().

```
InputSimulator cmd = new InputSimulator();

        if (e.KeyPressEvent.KeyPressState.Equals("BREAK"))
        {
            cpt = 0;
            Console.WriteLine(e.KeyPressEvent.Name);
            //Check the Device name first !!!!
            //if(e.KeyPressEvent.Name.Contains(Settings.Default.DeviceName) || Settings.Default.DeviceName.Contains(e.KeyPressEvent.Name)) { }
            String ActiveProcess = ActiveApp.getActiveProccess();

          switch (ActiveProcess)
            {
                case "chrome":
                    if(API.getChromeUrl().Contains("facebook") || API.getChromeUrl().Contains("messenger"))
                    {

                        switch (e.KeyPressEvent.VKeyName)
                        {
                            case "NUMPAD0":
                                cmd.Keyboard.TextEntry(FBEmo.numpad0);
                                break;
```